# how to move view to the center of screen using animations in android

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-animation, android-view

i'd like to move a view (in my case - a button, but it doesn't really matter) to the center of the screen. 
when i'm running the move without animations, it works. 
however, i'm having a hard time deciding which animations i should use to do so, since TranslateAnimation only lets me do so but specify the exact x,y coordinates, which i don't have (tried it with metrics, but the calculation didn't work, and i don't want to use this method).

So, this code works without animations :

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
parms2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
parms2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
_buttonC.setLayoutParams(parms2);
```

and when i try to add animations, it doesn't.

```
ObjectAnimator ani = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(_buttonC, "Y", 2000);
ani.setDuration(4000);
ani.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        parms2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        parms2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        _buttonC.setLayoutParams(parms2);               
    }


    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
    {

    }
});
```

any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
_buttonC.animate().translationX(parentCenterX - _buttonC.getWidth()/2).translationY(parentCenterY - _buttonC.getHeight()/2);
```

Of course you will have to calculate the parent centerX and centerY:

```
float parentCenterX = parent.getX() + parent.getWidth()/2;
float parentCenterY = parent.getY() + parent.getHeight()/2;
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: It should be `translationX(parentCenterX - _buttonC.getWidth()/2 - _buttonC.getX())`

Answer (score 0):

First. You need get screen coordinates(class [Point](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Point)). From onCreate launch this method.

```
    fun getWindowSize():Point{
    val display = windowManager.defaultDisplay
    val size = Point()
    display.getSize(size)
    val width: Int = size.x
    val height: Int = size.y
    return size
}
```

Second. You need:

1. calculate where is centre
2. calculate size of a view that you want to move and divide it to 2
3. subtract from center half the moving view size
4. use [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator) to move the view

   ```
    protected fun toCentre(view: View){
    //get centre
    val windowXcentre = size.x / 2
    val windowYcentre = size.y / 2
    //half size of moving view
    val viewWidth = view.width /2
    val viewHeight = view.height/2
    //wher to move
    val x = windowXcentre - viewWidth.toFloat()
    val y = windowYcentre - viewHeight.toFloat()
    //move it
    view.animate().x(x).y((y))
   ```

   }

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is the problem but please try:

```
ObjectAnimator ani = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(_buttonC, "translationY", 2000);
...
ani.start();
```

Comment: You don't have to use ani.start() - just use translationY instead of Y

Answer (score -1):

private void moveSearchViewDown() {
        View edit_text = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int mid = metrics.heightPixels/2 - edit_text.getHeight();

    ObjectAnimator positionAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(edit_text, View.Y, mid);
    positionAnimation.start();
}
```